# Persisting User Sessions with Httponly Cookies in React

Tags: reactjs, express, security

I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to fetch user data / persist user sessions on the client side via React, when using HttpOnly cookies to store session data.

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
useEffect( () => {

const getSession = async () => {
   const session = await fetch('/session/current')

   if(session){
       .... there is an active session
        .... set the local state to hold user data
      }   
   }

   getsession();
}
```

So the issue I'm trying to figure out is, when the user logs in and closes the browser, then re-enters my website. How do I validate that the user still has a valid session, and then send necessary user data to the client side to know that the user is authenticated?

When the user logs in and cloes the browser, there is still a valid session HttpOnly cookie on the server side. Is the best way to just hit an endpoint, see if there is a valid session, then return user data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle this from client side as it is an httponly cookie. You need to send the cookie to the backend to validate session. If users close and reopen their browser, they loose their cookies. In order to keep them logged in you will need to track some other information from the user like their IP address, OS, browser type, etc and save it in like memory cache for a ttl. But it is not secure to do it that way.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, once your get the cookie or token from the server after user logs in, you will have to store in it local session storage in browser itself, so if user closes the browser and reopens it would have automatically logged out,

Or do mention ttl, so that it will have some expiry time as well

Comment: As I've mentioned, this is using an HttpOnly cookie. The whole point is to avoid storing anything on the client.