# How to make a secure way for user login and handeling with react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, security, authentication, cookies

I am trying to make a secure way to proove that a user is logged in within my react app.
Currently when the user loggs in i save his user id to the local storage. After a while i found out that this isn't save enough because you just can open dev tools and eddit the values of the localstorage. So how can i do this so that you can't type in someones user id and be logged in as the selected user? I googled this and found out that you can use cookies. I am also planing to do this but i also looked at the devtools and saw that it is also possible to edit them. So i think i need to change something in my code maybe an extra token or an encoded user id or something. But i realy dont have a clue on how to deal with this so that it is realy secure? Hope someone at least could point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot for every answer.

Comment: Did you create the API you are calling? Or are you Firebase? Could you explain the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is so true saving a token for example JWT in local storage or cookies this is not a safe way of handling user sessions. Because with JavaScript one can interact with the local storage of cookie(if they are **not httpOnly** cookies).

**What is the best way of handling user sessions then?**

- The solution that you would want to explore is server side session cookies
- So server side session cookies will be made from your dedicated server and have it set the cookie in your browser and flag it as **httpOnly**.
- So by this said no script written can interact with that cookie cause it is an httpOnly cookie

**If you are using both React and Node:**

- If your using the two I would advise that you look into Express-sessions

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply.
I am also using typeorm express for backend calls.
When i am in production i am using also express to proxy my api request.
Where should i implement the express sessions then?

Comment: Another Update for @Ntshembo s post: I implemented an httpOnly cookie to my express application and i was able to set an httpOnly cookie. However i am still able to edit it with the Devtools. Should i be able to edit it? Because like i said if it is so i probably need to insert something else than the userID in this cookie because then everyone could still (and this was my problem in the first place) log in as another user by editing this cookie.

Comment: Express-session is made in your Node server. Secondly if you are able to interact with the cookie that means that there is an error in your implementation or either that cookie is not an httpOnly cookie. to help you on how to implement an httpOnly cookie check out this response that I gave it has a detailed example of how to implement express-sessions and save that in your MongoDB plus setting the cookie in your react app as httpOnly cookie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760619/handling-sessions-with-httponly-cookies-in-react/64760847#64760847

Comment: Thanks a lot but my problem is that i use a mysql db. How is the setup different from MongoDB